# Need help crafting an elegant LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, data-structures

I have an object called waferMap that contains list of bluetapes; each bluetape contains a list of die prints and each die print has a name.  I need to be able to pull out a die print based off of its name from the bluetape list and if it does not exist, I need it to return null, not crash the application.

To sum up the hierarchy:

```
WaferMap has a List<BlueTape>
BlueTape has a List<DiePrint>
DiePrint has name (of type string)
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    print = waferMap.BluetapeList
                    .Select(x => x.DiePrintList)
                    .First(x => x.Contains(print, new DiePrint.Comparer()))
                    .First(x => x.Name == print.Name);
```

And here is the comparer object from the DiePrint class:

```
    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<DiePrint>
    {
        public bool Equals(DiePrint x, DiePrint y) { return x.Name == y.Name; }
        public int GetHashCode(DiePrint obj) { return obj.Name.GetHashCode(); }
    }
```

Right now it always finds a match for some reason, even if no die print in any of the bluetapes die print list exists with the appropriate name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
waferMap.BluetapeList
        .SelectMany(bt => bt.DiePrintList)
        .FirstOrDefault(dp => dp.Name == print.Name);
```

SelectMany flattens lists [(docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: It still seems to be finding a match every time.  If print.Name = "-1x8" (which will never exist), it still pulls out something.  If I put an object ID on it, it seems to always be returning the same object.  Sometimes I even get two results which is never really the case since every DiePrint.Name is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution might be as easy as checking for nulls in your `Equals` method of your comparer.

```
public bool Equals(DiePrint x, DiePrint y)
{
    if (x == null && y == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (x == null || y == null) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }
}
```

That's the first place where "when something's null it crashes the program" jumps out at me. If this still doesn't work, then we'll need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SelectMany` to flatten each of the collections, filter on what you need to, and use `FirstOrDefault` to get the first item but defaulting if there is none to returning the default value of that type (in this case, null).

```
var query = from wafer in wafers
    from tape in wafer.Tapes
    from die in tape
    where die.Name == print.Name
    select tape;

var firstTape = query.FirstOrDefault();
```